# AzPowerShell Script Task in Deployment Pipeline. What are some of the ways to resolve a Conflict error when Removing and Create an Az Storage Table

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-powershell, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have an Azure DevOps Deployment Pipeline with an Azure PowerShell Script Task.

The script task populates an Azure Storage Table.  It gets the data from a json file.

Unfortunately, my client keeps on changing their mind with what they want in the table.

So, I thought the best thing to do would be to delete the table, recreate it and repopulate it with the new data.

But, I get a conflict error if I run the Remove and Create back-to-back.  Which makes sense since it seems so much of Azure uses a messaging architecture.

Anyway, does anyone have a solution to this issue? I have a few, but they seem jerry-rigged.

Here a subset of the codde:

```
$storageAccount = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -AccountName $StorageAccountName

$storageTable = Get-AzStorageTable `
    -Name $tableName `
    -Context $storageAccount.Context `
    -ErrorVariable ev `
    -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

if($storageTable) {
    Remove-AzStorageTable -Name $tableName -Context $storageAccount.Context -Force     
}

New-AzStorageTable -Name $tableName -Context $storageAccount.Context

$storageTable = Get-AzStorageTable -Name $tableName -Context $storageAccount.Context
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done a few modifications to your code. Please follow the below snippet

```
$storageAccount = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -AccountName $StorageAccountName

$storageTable = Get-AzStorageTable `
    -Name $tableName `
    -Context $storageAccount.Context `
    -ErrorVariable ev `
    -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
# if you dont have the table it will gives the $ev so you have to capture this and if table is not there we have to create
if ($ev) {
    New-AzStorageTable -Name $tableName -Context $storageAccount.Context
    $isDeleted = $false
    write-host("Table is not there it is created")
}
# if table exist you can remove the table
elseif($storageTable.Name -eq $tableName) {
    Remove-AzStorageTable -Name $tableName -Context $storageAccount.Context
    $isDeleted = $true
    write-host("Table is there so it is Removed")
    # After deleting table we have to wait for 40 sec to completely delete the table from Garbage. Mean while we cannot access the table storage.
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 40 
}


if($isDeleted -eq $true)
{
    
    New-AzStorageTable -Name $tableName -Context $storageAccount.Context
    write-host("Table is Removed so it is created")
}

$storageTable = Get-AzStorageTable -Name $tableName -Context $storageAccount.Context
```

> After **Deleting/Removing** a table it is immediately marked for deletion and is no longer accessible to clients is likely to take at least `40 seconds` to complete on that time it will be in a Garbage collection. Refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Delete-Table?redirectedfrom=MSDN#remarks)

#### Results:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for response.  It solved my issue.